# Tensorflow: training and evaluation process

Tags: tensorflow, evaluation, training-data, object-detection-api

I am using Tensorflow to train my data-set (with Object-detection API) locally with 1080 Nvidia 8GB,

I use `create_pet_tf_record.py` to generate TFRecords files. I don't train from scratch I use `mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt` as a `fine_tune_checkpoint`.

When I run `python object_detection/train.py` and `/eval.py`, I check the training and evaluation process thru Tensorboard. Initially, everything seems correct like this [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tqst.png) with zero step.

The training checkpoint interval takes long time to be saved. After more than `5,000` training steps, the evaluation moved from `/model.ckpt-0` to `/model.ckpt-3642` and the whole process will be NOT okay at this moment as shown in this [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gefis.png).

This is my file `mask_rcnn_inception_v2.config`

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 375
        width: 500
      }
    }
    number_of_stages: 3
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        predict_instance_masks: true
        mask_height: 15
        mask_width: 15
        mask_prediction_conv_depth: 0
        mask_prediction_num_conv_layers: 2
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
        conv_hyperparams {
          op: CONV
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
    second_stage_mask_prediction_loss_weight: 4.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0002
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00002
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000002
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0

  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/jesse/gpu-py3/models/research/object_detection/models/model/mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_train/mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/jesse/gpu-py3/models/research/ttt/pet_train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/jesse/gpu-py3/models/research/object_detection/data/pet_label_map.pbtxt"
  load_instance_masks: true
  mask_type: PNG_MASKS
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/jesse/gpu-py3/models/research/ttt/pet_val.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/jesse/gpu-py3/models/research/object_detection/data/pet_label_map.pbtxt"
  load_instance_masks: true
  mask_type: PNG_MASKS
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

I don't know where I am mistaken, I feel like I should run evaluation more often, and the training checkpoint should be saved every 2000 steps for example. Or I may need to edit the pipeline file `mask_rcnn_inception_v2.config`. I don't know why the training result is very disappointed after `3642` steps as seen in [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb9Eg.png).

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents on this, assuming you have not modified the important config parameters much, your training data is very diverse and as more iterations go through its generalising. Try with more accurate labelling of images, even if it means fewer images.

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried with other images that I also labeled them, but same issue. Could you please clarify your answar ?

Comment: Do you mean that I incorrect labeled my images. I used this tool for annotation https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg and this tool for Segmentation Class https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/tree/master/examples/instance_segmentation

Comment: annotations (xml files) and segmentation class to be placed in trimaps folder

Comment: Ya i am leaning towards labelling being not accurate